# Migrating website project built in VS2010 to VS2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

How can I successfully run vs2010 website project in vs2012 and create `edmx` without `.tt` file?

We have run the project with vs2012 but we are facing an issue with `.tt` file. A lot of our websites are built using vs2010 & .Net framework 4.0.

Any ideas to solve this issue would be helpful.

Comment: Could you specify wich website you are trying to migrate? Aspx? Mvc? What errors do you get to see in VS2012? It would be easier to help if we had more information. I migrated a few mvc projects from vs2010 to vs2012, and i never experienced any trouble. Here is some more indepth info about .TT files, maybe you can find some help in there. http://www.olegsych.com/2007/12/text-template-transformation-toolkit/

Comment: Can't VS 2012 read the VS 2010 solution, and therefore you could use your apps as is using .NET 4.0?

Comment: for Aspx Currently it is working fine with old edmx without tt file in vs2012 but Our old edmx created in vs2010(without tt file).now when we try to create new edmx file in vs2012 it will create .tt file with edmx. is it required to have a TT file with VS2012  ?? can't we just create edmx that we did with VS2010 ??